# Handlebars nodejs getting errors

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js

I am writing NodeJS app that uses Handlebars to serve some compiled HTML.

```cs
express = require 'express'
handlebars = require 'handlebars'
fs = require 'fs'

express().get '/foo.html', ->
    fooData = {isFoo:true}

    template = handlebars.compile fs.readFileSync('foo-template.html').toString()

    htmlString = template(data)
    res.send htmlString
```

But, my foo.html file has some errors.

```html
<html>
    {{#if isFoo}}
        What's up foo
    <!-- closing {{/if}} tag is missing -->
</html>
```

When I visit '/foo.html', the server seems to work fine, but my request just hangs. Something must have gone wrong. *Why isn't Handlebars throwing some kind of exception?*

Or, how can I ensure that Handlebars is throwing exceptions for me as I write foo.html?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with how Handlebars or Express handles the errors. The issue is that I was using https://github.com/kriskowal/q properly. Q eats any errors and sends it into its `.catch ->`

My *actual* code snippet was something more like this:

```coffeescript
express = require 'express'
handlebars = require 'handlebars'
fs = require 'fs'
Q = require 'q'

doStuff = ->
  def = Q.defer()
  doAsynchronousThings ->
    def.resolve()
  def.promise

express().get '/foo.html', ->

  doStuff().then ->

    fooData = {isFoo:true}

    template = handlebars.compile fs.readFileSync('foo-template.html').toString()

    htmlString = template(data)
    res.send htmlString

  # here is what I should have included
  #.catch (e) -> 
  #   console.log e
```